# Python - Pyplot x-axis not showing on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

pyplot is not showing the x-axis on the graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sitka_weather_2014.csv')    

df['AKST'] = pd.to_datetime(df.AKST)
df['Dates'] = df['AKST'].dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y')
df.set_index("Dates", inplace= True)

# Plot Data
fig = plt.figure(dpi=256, figsize=(14, 7))
plt.title("Daily high and low temperature - 2014")

df['Max TemperatureF'].plot(linewidth=1, c='blue', label="Max Temperature °F")
df['Min TemperatureF'].plot(linewidth=1, c='red', label="Min Temperature °F")

plt.grid(True)
plt.rc('grid', linestyle=":", linewidth=1, color='gray')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.xlabel('', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel("Temperature (°F)", fontsize=10)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

The x-axis should be the index of the Pandas Dataframe (df) containing the dates.

[image]

Comment: Please note that you should always provide a [mcve], such that the code can be run by others. Otherwise how should people be able to know at which point this fails?

Comment: cannot simulate your problem. It looks ok when I used my own sample data. How do you run python? via notebook?

Comment: @anonyXmous Yes, I run python via the Junyper notebook, but using the IDE get the same.

Comment: can you show us how you define the dataframe (df)? Also include the data if possible.

Comment: @anonyXmous I have included the entire code and the csv can be obtain here:  https://github.com/crystalDf/Python-Crash-Course-Chapter-15-Data-Visualization/blob/master/sitka_weather_2014.csv

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have included the entire code and the csv can be obtain here:  https://github.com/crystalDf/Python-Crash-Course-Chapter-15-Data-Visualization/blob/master/sitka_weather_2014.csv

Comment: I cannot simulate your problem and it shows Jan 01 -> Dec 17, 2014. Also, i fixed your code and put set_index after creating 'Date' column.

Comment: The code as it is cannot run, since there is no "Dates" column in the original dataframe. First make sure to have a [mcve] in the question. If correcting for that error the resulting plot looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJpP.png). So you may have modified something compared to the standard settings, which we cannot know what it is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Indeed, the 'Dates' column is not in the original df, but I created it and set it as index when I issue this piece of code:df['AKST'] = pd.to_datetime(df.AKST)
df['Dates'] = df['AKST'].dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y')
df.set_index("Dates", inplace= True)

Comment: I have added the [pandas] tag, because you plot using a dataframe's method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually fine. I tried to run it with the necessary `sitka_weather_2014.csv` file and it works.

The problem is that you can't see the x-axis because the size of the figure is too big, and thus the description of the x-axis dissapears. Try to scale your figure e.g. by making the `dpi` smaller:

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(14, 7)) #dpi=100 instead of dpi=256
```

Or make the `labelsize` smaller:

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=5) #labelsize=5 instead of labelsize=10
```

Whatever works best for you. But the code is fine and the description of the x-axis is showing.

Comment: @daquezada I saw that you have made some edits to the code you posted here on StackOverflow. Did you also run the code which is currently shown (Maybe copy and paste it to be sure)? Because the current one works for me...

Comment: @V.L. In the comments below the question two people already said that the code does produce a plot *with* labels. I doubt it makes sense to answer, again saying that the code is fine. As long as the questioner does not make his problem reproducible, there is simply no answer to this question.

Comment: @V.L. If the code works for all of you, except me, I believe is the right time to start assuming the the problem might be with my IDE.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `xlabel` value set to `null`:

```py
plt.xlabel('', fontsize=10)
```

Comment: This may not solve the problem completely because there should be tick labels as well. Please consider updating the answer.